# Empty optional element error?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have an element, `labels`, whose `minoccurs="0"` and `minLength="1"`.

```
<xs:element name="labels" type="x2x:labels" minOccurs="0" />

<xs:simpleType name="labels">
        <xs:restriction> 
            <xs:simpleType> 
                <xs:list itemType="xs:token" />
            </xs:simpleType>    
            <xs:minLength value="1" /> 
        </xs:restriction> 
    </xs:simpleType>
```

When the `labels` is not set I get the following error:

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; 
>   cvc-minLength-valid: Value '' with length = '0' is not facet-valid with respect to minLength '1' for type 'labels'.

As per my knowledge, if `minOccurs=0` and I am not setting the element, it should not given any error as it's meant to be optional.

Comment: Please show the XML that is failing validation

Comment: It's not set, meaning the element still is in the document? Then it occurs once and should have content. Or "it's not set" as in it doesn't occur in the document?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: It's not set as in, I don't call the setter of the label attribute when filling my POJO

Comment: So it's not only about XSD, it's about serialization. You still get the element there, just an empty one. It's easier to explain the whole situation at once. You cannot have minOccurs in this case then.

Comment: But earlier, my XSD had `minOccurs=0` and `minLength` was not mentioned and it was working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was sending **empty** element i.e they were by default being set to empty list. Thus there was the exception as `minLen="1"` would not accept empty elements and `minoccurs="0"` was satisfied as element was set (occurenece was true).

Answer (score 1):

> minLength '1' for type 'labels'.

it is logic, if you did not use the `labels`, it gets value 0, at `<xs:minLength value="1" />`, is your problem. Change it or set a value. 
Change  `<xs:restriction>` with `<xs:restriction base="xs:string">` if it is a string.

Comment: @Chrystain:  I didn't understand your answer. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Your value is NULL at start, right? If your min is 1, NULL < 1 so It won`t respect your rule, change it with 0,  try to change it with  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">

Comment: @Chrystain: But `minOcuurs=0` says it can be optional. So if I am not setting it,  shouldn't it  work ?

Comment: Listen carefully.  If your XML includes a `labels` element, that element's value must have length >= 1 in order to be valid.  Declaring it with `minOccurs="0"` means the element is not required to appear, for its parent to be valid, not that it can occur with a value that doesn't conform to the declaration.  Nothing in the XSD validator gives two cents whether you called a Java `set` method on it or not.  You might want to read up on your serialization method; maybe you can make it behave better.

Answer (score 1):

### XSD

The following XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:x2x="http://www.example.com/x2x"
           targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/x2x">

  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="labels" type="x2x:labels" minOccurs="0" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:simpleType name="labels">
    <xs:restriction> 
      <xs:simpleType> 
        <xs:list itemType="xs:token" />
      </xs:simpleType>    
      <xs:minLength value="0" /> 
    </xs:restriction> 
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

successfully validates both of the following XML documents because it allows

1. `labels` to be absent per `minOccurs="0"`, and
2. `labels` to be present with empty content per `minLength="0"` (not `1`, which would cause the error you were receiving).

### XML, no `labels`

```
<x2x:root/>
```

### XML, empty `labels`

```
<x2x:root>
  <labels/>
</x2x:root>
```